# Failed to write all bytes for MSVCR100.dll

Tags: python, windows-server-2008-r2, msvcr100.dll

I made a python console exe. It cannot work on windows2008 R2 server.

I copy MSVCR100.dll and MSVCP100.dll from another computer onto the dir containing the exe file. It has been working correctly a long time.

Today, when start it show that "Failed to write all bytes for MSVCR100.dll"

I don't know what caused it and how to deal with it.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Suggestion: there is a difference between Python 32bits and 64bits. If you developed your exe on Python 32bit, you must re-create a virtualenv and reinstall on Python 64bits. This may be the reason why you need to copy the DLL.

Comment: yes,the exe is developed on PY32bit.But when i copy the dlls,it has been working correctly many days.i dont know why it doesn't work today.Did you mean that try to develop exe on Python 64bit?

Comment: Yes, You need a 64bits Python environment (download it if necessary) create a virtualenv and install your application (you can install from source with `pip`). Then, you can deploy this virtualenv on your target server.

Comment: i found that c disk is full.when i deleted some file,everything got right.thank you all the same.

Answer (score 0):

The "Failed to write all bytes for (random DLL name)" error generally indicates that the disk is full. Would be nice if Microsoft had bothered to add an extra sentence indicating such, but this is usually the problem.

If your disk isn't full, then it may be a permissions issue -- make sure the user you're running the program as has write access to wherever it's trying to write to.